# Missing Triangulation Libraries in OpenCV:

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv, netbeans-6.9

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 to develop Delaunay triangulation code on NetBeans 6.9 on Ubuntu 11.04.  I have included all of the libraries that I could find in the link list but get the following error messages when I try to link.

```
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/1942517469/TwoDTriangulation.o: In function `cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D': 
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h:376: undefined reference to `cvCreateSubdiv2D' 
/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h:378: undefined reference to `cvInitSubdivDelaunay2D'
```

Comment: Sorry.  I meant link, not compile.

Comment: Did you try to download the sources and include these files from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those symbols are defined in `libopencv_imgproc.so`, which means that if you were compiling the app through cmd-line with **g++** you would have to add the `-lopencv_imgproc` flag.